# I get logs 2 times in stdout when there is a traceback error in django

Tags: python, django, python-logging

my settings.py for LOGGER is as below,

```
LOGGING = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': False,
'formatters': {
    'json': {
        '()': 'sample_app.json_log_formatter.JSONFormatter',
    },
  },
'handlers': {
    'console': {
        'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        'stream': sys.stdout,
        #'level': '',
        'formatter': 'json'
    },
},
'loggers': {
    '': {
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'level': 'INFO',
        #'propogate': True,
    },
},
}
```

Now when there is any unhandled exceptions like var = abc and abc is not defined I get my logs 2 times,

one with my handler so the traceback error is in json format and the second is again the same error without json format it is coming from django.request.

Note: I have not added any extra logger line in my code . I just want all my unhandled exceptions also in json format but only once. so that when I send to ELK its clean

Answer (score 0):

I got the settings changes as below,

```
'loggers': {
    '': {
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'propogate': True,
    },
    'django': {
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'propagate': False,
        'level': 'INFO'
    },
```

So here we making ll default django request to INFO level and propagate to false so it will not appear once . And this will override the root level logging config where in above example DEBUG is default for other applications (like my django apps) and INFO level for django logs.